# Use let variable in different functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, ecmascript-6

in my application I need somewhere store global variable which will be used just by one method. I am using in front end javascript (jquery).

my code looks like this:

```
$(function () {
    let myVar;
    // ...
};

// and method
function foo() {
   if (!myVar) {
      // calculate myVar
   }

   // do something with myVar and update its value
}
```

Problem is I can't see myVar in that method. I also tried use localStorage and sessionStorage. but when I refresh page value is still set. I need compute new value after page refresh and no use previous one.

What is the best practice for storing variable in my case? Thank you in advice.

Comment: `window.myVar = "value";`

Comment: `What is the best practice`  Storing on window global is certainly not best practice.  It really depends, the best approach is to use a module loader, and you could store globals in a module.  In your example you could even use scope by placing the `foo` function inside your jQuery callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a property on window object. This works in the browser context

```
window["myVar"] = "myValue";
```

Answer (score 1):

The let keyword has block scope - it will not be accessible outside of its block of code (function, loop, conditional, etc.) You should assign it directly to the window object:

```
window["myVar"] = "A value";
```

Comment: `var` has functional scope, so in the OP's example it makes no difference if you change the `let` to a `var`..

Comment: Oh yes, forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

Further to @Vlandu lonuts post:

`window.myVar` means that your variable is being declared right at the very top of the global scope. This means that any of your JavaScript code will have access to this variable.